# How to improve performance of Angular JS 2 applications in IE?

Tags: angular

In IE interaction are slow, due to the wrong implementation of app the IE interaction are very slow how even browser stuck few times.

Comment: One option is to move to Angular v2. They've done a significant amount of work to improve performance.

Comment: But IE interactions are very slow, I mean it taking 3 seconds for any event to occur. example: when the user clicks a button, we need to wait for some time to see the click action.

Comment: You haven't given *any* information here that would make this answerable.  Which version of Angular? Which version of IE? Which functions in angular are slow? How much data are you trying to display? What other libraries are in use? You may want to take some time to improve your question. See [ask].

Comment: IE 11 and Angular 2.4 with  material 2

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue in IE, we need to use the ngDestroy() and *ngIf carefully to increase the performance.